# Getting x and y co-ordinates of graph while touch in android

Tags: android, canvas, graph, drawing, coordinates

I want to draw a line on a graph in Android. When clicking on the particular portion of the graph, I am not able to get the particular x and y coordinates of the graph. How can I retrieve them?

Comment: Hi, Please put some more information, like is your graph any custom library or just you created using canvas, please if you used any listener or not also some code snippet, Then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MotionEvent to get x and y coordinates

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
          int x = (int)event.getX();
          int y = (int)event.getY();

          return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use View.getLocationOnScreen(int[]) to get X and Y of a graph relative to its parent/screen.

```
  `int[] posXY = new int[2];
    myView.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
    int x = posXY[0];
    int y = posXY[1];`
```

Comment: @Gowtham Can you please post some code for a better understanding of the issue?